# How to organize your custom files directories (Rails 6.1.3.2)?

Tags: ruby, file, directory, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm following a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/8SLdV8dn7_I) on twilio sms service, and I came to a point where I have to create my own `.rb` file! My project directory at the moment looks something like this:

The tutorial uses `atom my_ruby_file.rb` in the terminal to create a new ruby file. However, I do not use atom and from what I understand rails have changed a lot since 2014 that the video was recorded!

So my question is: **Where to create my custom ruby files for `Rails 6.1.3.2`?** I have noticed in my directory that `.rb` files are used all over the place. For example `controllers` and `models` and more, but where do I have to set one created by me ?

Related Question:

**Where to keep other custom files such as `.js`, `.css`, `.png` ?** The way I did it is to create a new folder in the following directory `project-name/app/javascript/my_custom_files/js/dial_codes.js` and actually reference that in the `project-name/app/javascript/packs/application.js` using this command `require("my_custom_files/js/dial_codes")`. **Is this the correct way of doing that for that specific rails version?**

```
 project-name
  |
  |- app
       |- assets
       |- channels (application_cable)
       |- controllers (concerns) -> contains application_controller.rb, friends_controller.rb, home_controller.rb
       |- helpers
       |- javascript (channels, packs, my_custom_files) -> For custom JS, CSS, images using webpacker 
       |- jobs
       |- mailers
       |- models (concerns) -> contains application_record.rb, friend.rb, users.rb 
       |- views (divise, friends, home, layouts) 
  |- bin
  |- config
       |- environments
       |- initializers
       |- locales
       |- webpack
  |- db
  |- lib
  |- log
  |- .node_modules
  |- public
  |- storage
  |- test
  |- tmp
  |- vendor
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'custom ruby file'? If it's a model it goes into `app/models`, if it's a controller it goes into `app/controllers`, is that what you're looking for? In general: put your custom files where they belong - so right in all those Rails folders. They're all yours :-)

Comment: And sometimes you have ruby files that are not so obvious to sort away in existing folders. You can use the `lib` folder for those. But I think it's common now to move the `lib` folder to `app/lib`, because of auto-loading.

Comment: I think you're putting the cart before the horse. Spend some time reading up on the Rails directory structure, the MVC framework, and adding custom code to Rails. There's no simple or "right" answer to this question. You need a stronger understanding of the fundamentals, and while @Josien's answers are helpful they don't paint the full picture. (and you're unlikely to get a comprehensive answer here because this question has been asked a lot of times in a lot of ways)

Comment: Yeah I figured that the hard way :( But thanks for your comments, will do. Should I delete the question?